# Textarea above bootstrap modal doesn't get focus

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have a chat, which has a textarea part for typing. Works good.

I open a modal, the textarea still remains above, due to z-index. However it doesn't get focus when I click with the mouse. Looks like it's disabled.

It doesn't work also if I open the chat after I opened the modal.

Any ideas?

The chat window has absolute positioning.

Comment: Please, post the peace of code.

Comment: I don't have any idea of what causes this problem

Comment: post the HTML peace to compose the modal : some think like ...
    `<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header"> ` ...

Comment: There is something to do with bootstrap modal and absolute positioning

Comment: Try update this example to stay like your code: http://codepen.io/edgardleal/pen/ZeLdOL?editors=1000

Comment: Just add at the end <textarea style='position:absolute;z-index:100000'></textarea>

Comment: Can you write something in textarea when modal is opened?

Comment: Yes.I updated this pen with your `style` and I can type in textarea yet.
I think the problem could be on CSS.

Comment: Try to open the modal, and after that type in textarea, which I added. Due to z-index it will be above

Comment: Please show your pen, if you still can type

Comment: I don'd understand your purpose. The textarea is not visible before show the modal , right ? 
You can edit the code in this link http://codepen.io/edgardleal/pen/ZeLdOL?editors=1010 save and share with me.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMpLxZ?editors=1010.    Open the modal, and then try to type in textarea, which has absolute position. Textarea, which i added, is always visible. It has 100000 z-index

Comment: I can't find any way to do that. I recommend you to don't use Boostrap modal, only create a div with `position: fixed` and high z-index to show your chat.

Comment: I tried with https://github.com/jgthms/bulma and it works fine.

Comment: Give the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that I don't know, Boostrap don't permit do that.

I make some think like this using Bulma ( a pure css lib ):

```
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Any other Bulma elements you want -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Jhon</td>
          <td>Hi</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="text" class="input" />
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close"></button>
  </div>
  <textarea style="position:absolute;z-index: 9999" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <p>
    <button class="button" id="showModal">Show</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Bulma don't have JavaScript code, and you should make the transition of classes yourself.

JavaScript:

```
$("#showModal").click(function() {
  $(".modal").addClass("is-active");  
});

$(".modal-close").click(function() {
   $(".modal").removeClass("is-active");
});
```

http://codepen.io/edgardleal/pen/GWWKoO?editors=1010

Comment: I need to deal with bootstrap modal